# emacs elpy/jedi code completion: popup window not working properly

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, jedi, elpy

I am using elpy/jedi for code completion. As you can see in the images, when the popup opens is broken. It looks like two different windows are open at the same time (could the second one be auto-complete ???). The one is python suggestions and the other seems like other kind of suggestions.

Nothing weird in my setup:

```
; enable elpy
(package-initialize)
(elpy-enable)

;; jedi
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)                 ; optional
```

I tried to disable other stuff e.g. ac-complete-clang or auto-complete-c-headers but does not seem to be the issue.

Also as you can see in the last image, suggestions for list 'l' are both apply and append (apply overlaps with append: l.applyend).

Any suggestion? Anyone else with a similar issue?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 3]

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody is facing this issue in 2020 I solved it by disabling `fci-mode`. There is an issue with `company-mode` as indicated [here](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/180).

If it is your case and still need a vertical line at col 80 you can use `display-fill-column-indicator-mode` which is included by default since Emacs 27.

Answer (score 2):

`elpy` and `jedi` each offer auto-completion and are conflicting with each other. Try turning one off and loading a new python buffer.